# How to allow Phoenix handle multiple domains?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

A web  application in Phoenix. Nginx is used as a reverse proxy.

At the moment, as it normally will, the web application handles requests for a single domain. If I point DNS of other domains to the same server, what will I have to change to let my Phoenix application to handle request for those domains?

The web application on the server will remain in the single instance . And it will become accessible via multiple domains. There'll be no redirect to the main domain -- each domain will handle requests as if it was the main domain.

Answer (score 6):

The place to configure the host(s) your Phoenix application will use, is in the configuration of the `Phoenix.Endpoint`.

Three configuration fields of `Phoenix.Endpoint` need to be changed from their defaults:

- `url: [host: ...]` This should be the fallback hostname to use in url helpers or redirects. Note whenever you pass a `conn` (or `socket`) to an URL helper, it will use the fields from there.
- `check_origin:`

  - If set to true (which is the default), Phoenix will reject requests with an `origin` header asking for a hostname not not equal to the `url: [host: ...]` field above.
  - If set to a list of hostnames, it will accept any of the listed hostnames. **This is what you want if you have a fixed set of multiple hostnames**. Each of the hostname strings supports wildcards (so e.g. you could match any subdomain using `*.example.com`)
  - If set to false, you disable origin checking. This 'always works' but it poses a security risk. (Cross-Site WebSocket Hijacking attacks) so consider it an option of last resort. Only use this if your app's hostnames dynamically change (and if you do, make sure you do your own origin check elsewhere in the code).
- `force_ssl: [host: ...]` By default, any incoming HTTP request is redirected to the hostname set here. If the `host:` field is missing in this list of options, it defaults to reading the `url: [host: ...]` mentioned above. If you explicitly set it to `host: nil`, it defaults to using the hostname which was used in the HTTP request. *Note that if you are handling SSL in the reverse proxy, this step is not required, as all traffic arriving at Phoenix will be HTTP in that case.*

What you will probably end up with, is something like:

```
# in config/runtime.exs (in ancient Elixir/Phoenix versions: config/prod.exs)
config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "mydomain1.com", port: 443, scheme: "https"],
  force_ssl: [host: nil],
  check_origin: [
    "https://mydomain1.com",
    "https://mydomain2.com",
    "https://*.mydomain3-and-all-its-subdomains.com",
  ]
```

[Phoenix.Endpoint configuration section in Phoenix' documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#module-endpoint-configuration)